# Unable to create a session object

Tags: java, hibernate

I use the code:

```
Session session = 
         new Configuration().
         configure(cfgurl).
         buildSessionFactory().
         openSession();
```

to create a session. The cfgUrl is of type URL and points to the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file of another project. The problem is that it is hanging and unable to proceed further. Why is this hanging?

Comment: Is the URL valid? Is the cfg file referred by it on the same machine, or over the network? Is it accessible e.g. via your browser?

Comment: Break up that line into multiple statements, so you can see which method call is the bad one. The way you've written, it could be any one of 4 method calls causing the problem.

Comment: the URL is valid and is one the same machine and accessible

Comment: Do a "kill -QUIT" to get a stacktrace to see where it hangs. Probably network, so also get a netstat as well.

Comment: the problem is in 
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure(cfgurl);
this statement.

Comment: @Steven It might help if you elaborated a little more **what** the problem exactly is with given statement.

Comment: it is getting hanged. i  broke up the statement and found out that the problem is in 
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure(cfgurl)
but dont know what it is

Comment: As suggested, generate a thread dump (kill -3 pid).

Answer (score 0):

Usually the SessionFactory is created once and kept in a static variable. I'm not sure that this is the cause of the hanging though.

Comment: Usually? Not on my my watch it ain't, that would be an offence worthy of a severe wagging of the finger.

Comment: @skaffman: alright then instead of "Usually" let's say "The method recommended in the hiberate documentation"

Comment: You _can_ create several session factories in the same project - although it is very rarely needed, thus almost always a waste of time and resources, it should work nevertheless. One of our app did that for a long time before I found and fixed it :-)

Comment: @skaffman don't just threaten with the wagging finger, explain your reasonings man. We might learn something that way. Perhaps you were confusing SessionFactory for Session though?